# Why does pandas value_counts() show a count of zero for some values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column is a categorical variable with the following labels: `['Short', 'Medium', 'Long', 'Very Long', 'Extremely Long']`.  I am trying to create a new dataframe that drops all the rows that are `Extremely Long`.

I have tried doing this in the following ways:

```
df2 = df.query('ride_type != "Extremely Long"')
df2 = df[df['ride_type'] != 'Extremely Long']
```

However, when I run .value_counts() I get the following:

```
df2.ride_type.value_counts()
>>> Short             130474
Long              129701
Medium            129607
Very Long         110988
Extremely Long         0
Name: ride_type, dtype: int64
```

In other words, `Extremely Long` is still there, so I can't plot charts with just the four categories I want.

Comment: If `df['ride_type'].dtype` is categorical, then missing categories are also recorded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of categorical data. You may have something that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ride_type': pd.Categorical(
    ['Long', 'Long'], categories=['Long', 'Short'])})

df
  ride_type
0      Long
1      Long
```

Calling `value_counts` on a categorical column will record counts for all categories, not just the ones present.

```
df['ride_type'].value_counts()    

Long     2
Short    0
Name: ride_type, dtype: int64
```

The solution is to either remove unused categories, or convert to string:

```
df['ride_type'].cat.remove_unused_categories().value_counts() 

Long    2
Name: ride_type, dtype: int64

# or,
df['ride_type'].astype(str).value_counts() 

Long    2
Name: ride_type, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drop rows like this:

```
df = df.drop(df.index[df['A'] == 'cat'])
print(df['A'].value_counts())

dog       2
rabbit    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```