# value_counts() shows counts from another pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm brand new with python and I'm playing around with data related to cars.
I've copied and reset index for new df

```
stelvio=pd.DataFrame(cars).copy()
stelvio.drop(stelvio[stelvio["model"]!="Stelvio"].index, inplace=True)
stelvio.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and wanted to check color count so I've run:

```
stelvio.color.value_counts()

Red           42
Grey          36
Black         36
White         30
Blue          21
Other          8
Green          5
Silver         3
Brown          3
Yellow         0
Gold           0
Purple         0
```

and

```
stelvio.info()
```

gives

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 184 entries, 0 to 183
```

There are now yellow or gold color cars in stelvio df, so **why I see them on value_counts() result for new df?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this comes from the fact that your data is seen as 'categorical' instead of strings - [Why does pandas value_counts() show a count of zero for some values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62090972/why-does-pandas-value-counts-show-a-count-of-zero-for-some-values) - explained here.

If that is the case, then you can do

```
stelvio.color.astype(str).value_counts()
```

and your '0 rows' should be gone